# first VirtualHost must be localhost in httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: virtualhost, wampserver

**Context:** fresh wampserver 3.x install (windows10)
port 80 was used by microsoft iis so i change the port using wampserver tool (right click on the icon). **Wampserver manage itself to change the port with 8080.**

at this moment, httpd-vhosts.conf content is

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and hosts content is:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost:8080
::1 localhost:8080
```

**Purpose:** create virtualhost for my project like http://myproject.localdev instead of http://localhost:8080/myproject/public/

**what's going bad ?**
by using wampserver link to create virtualhost, i got the error message below

```
first VirtualHost must be localhost in c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: I assume this means that you deleted the `localhost` Virtual Host that is by default placed into the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Is that what happened?

Comment: no, just as i said, fresh wampserver3 install then running wampserver tool to change port. Nothing made by my hand.

Comment: Can you show us what is in `c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.33/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` Add this to your question please

Comment: done (post edited)

Comment: I see, you have not yet tried, 1) open `localhost:8080` 2) Under TOOLS menu click **Add a Virtual Host** Follow the instructions

Comment: The port number is not supposed to be on the domain names in the HOSTS file

Comment: not sure about hosts file content was localhost:8080, i put this one from my memory.
This because i needed to solve the problem so i just disabled app who used port 80 then reaffect port 80 to wampserver ^^

Answer (score 1):

I used 8080 port too and had the same problem. What I've done - in `httpd-vhosts.conf` I added localhost with port 80 anyway, so I had both port 80 and port 8080:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
....
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
```

After that I opened localhost:8080 - there was a warning  "Port used for the VirtualHost is not an Apache Listen port". Newertheless I clicked "Add a Virtual Host". The new host was added, then I restarted DNS (WAMP - Tools - Restart DNS).

After all you can delete from `httpd-vhosts.conf` localhost:80